# Can not move file to another folder after Faraday::UploadIO telegram api

Tags: ruby, telegram, telegram-bot, faraday

I iterate the folder with images and if they don't fit the file size, I compress them and send the compressed version as a photo and the uncompressed version as a file. Then I wanted to move the uploaded file to another folder but I get an error
`Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (95880631_p0.jpg, uploaded\95880631_p0.jpg) (Errno::EACCES).`

My upload code below

```rb
Dir.glob("*.{jpg,png}").each do |file|
        p file
        if file.end_with? ".jpg"
            exten='image/jpeg'
        else 
            exten="image/png"
        end
        img_size=0

        check_image=MiniMagick::Image.open("#{file}")
        if check_image.dimensions.max>9000
            img_size=9000
        else
            img_size=check_image.dimensions.max
        end

        if check_image.size>5000000
            p "compressing #{file}"
            system 'mogrify -define jpeg:extent=5000kb -resize '+"#{img_size}x#{img_size}"+' -path compress -format jpg '+ "#{file}" if  !File.exist?('compress\\'+"#{file[..file.index(".")-1]}.jpg")
            check_image='compress\\'+"#{file[..file.index(".")-1]}.jpg"
        else
            check_image=file
        end

        if file.match?(/[0-9]_p[0-9]\.(jpg|png)/)#(/_p[0-9]+\./)
            bot.api.send_photo(
                chat_id: channel_id,
                photo: Faraday::UploadIO.new(check_image, exten),
                parse_mode:"MarkdownV2",
                caption: "[Source pixiv](https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/#{file[..file.index("_p")-1]})"
                )
        else
            bot.api.send_photo(
                chat_id: channel_id,
                photo: Faraday::UploadIO.new(check_image, exten)
                )
        end
        bot.api.send_document(chat_id:channel_id, document: Faraday::UploadIO.new(file, exten))
        
        
        FileUtils.mv(file, "uploaded\\#{file}")
    end
```

I checked that neither `MiniMagick::Image.open` nor `Dir.glob` causes this error, but only when I add a `Faraday::UploadIO` part

Is there any way to "close" UploadIO so that it does not affect the file? Or i need to do something else to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by separating UploadIO from function.

```
upld=Faraday::UploadIO.new(check_image, exten)
if file.match?(/[0-9]_p[0-9]\.(jpg|png)/)#(/_p[0-9]+\./)
    bot.api.send_photo(
        chat_id: channel_id,
        photo: upld,
        parse_mode:"MarkdownV2",
        caption: "[Source pixiv](https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/#{file[..file.index("_p")-1]})"
        )
else
    bot.api.send_photo(
        chat_id: channel_id,
        photo: upld
        )
end
upld.close
upld=Faraday::UploadIO.new(file, exten)
bot.api.send_document(chat_id:channel_id, document: upld)
upld.close
FileUtils.mv(file, "uploaded\\#{file}")
```